# How to scrape div.address text?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to access webpage elements that I may need to scrape.

I have a handle on how to access headers by tag name but I am having trouble with the div.address tag in the image.

The Inspect Element view
[image]

My code. Problem line is marked with +++++++:

```
Sub gettitleheader()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
    sURL = Cells(i, 1)

    wb.navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = True

    While wb.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'HTML document
    Set doc = wb.document

    On Error GoTo err_clear
    Cells(i, 2) = doc.getelementsbytagname("h1")(0).innerText

err_clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
    wb.Quit

    On Error GoTo err2_clear

    Cells(i, 3) = doc.getelementsbytagname("address")(0).innerHTML '+++++++

err2_clear:
    If Err2 <> 0 Then
        Err2.Clear
    Resume Next
    End If
    wb.Quit

    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Columns.AutoFit

Next i

End Sub
```

In the image below, the h1 tag is scraped and populated but not the address text.

Final output image, (I'm trying to fill that empty box)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question! so proud!

```
Sub gettitleheader()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
sURL = Cells(i, 1)

wb.navigate sURL
wb.Visible = True

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

'HTML document
Set doc = wb.document

On Error GoTo err_clear
Cells(i, 2) = doc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
y = doc.getElementsByClassName("address")(0).innerText
Do While (InStr(y, Chr(10)))
y = Right(y, Len(y) - 1)
Loop

z = y

Cells(i, 3) = z
err_clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
wb.Quit
```